# How to know the currentUser in parse server

Tags: javascript, express, parse-platform, parse-server

I am doing the register with express and Parse but when the login redirect to other view I want get the currentUser but this send undefined this is my code to login

```
exports.login_post = function(req, res) {
    Parse.User.logIn(req.body.username, req.body.password,{
        success: function(user) {
            if (user.get("tipoUsuario") == 1) {
                console.log("Usuario Administrador Logeado con Exito  "+user.id)
                res.redirect('/admin_admin');
            }
            if (user.get("tipoUsuario")==2){
                console.log("Usuario Restaurante Logeado con Exito   " + user.id)
                res.redirect('/edit_profile');
            } else {
                res.redirect('/');
            }
        },      
        error: function(user, error) {
            console.log(req.body.username);
            console.log(req.body.password);
            console.log("error"+error)
            res.redirect('/');
        }   
    }); 
};
```

But I cannot use `var currentUser = Parse.User.current();`

This returns as undefined.

Some know the other solution to get the currentUser?

Answer (score 0):

you can set a `session variable` to store your `current user`, later retrieve that user in your other views.

You can read how to set up session variable in this [documenatation](http://blog.modulus.io/nodejs-and-express-sessions). This will give you better insights and understanding on how to use session variables.

Set the session variable before redirect.

```
req.session.currUser= currentUser;
res.redirect('/');
```

Retrieve the session variable in the other views:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  var currUser= req.session.currUser;
  req.session.currUser= null; // reset the session variable after retrieving the value.
  // Do something
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was

```
exports.login = function(req, res){
var pathname = req.body.pathname;
Parse.User.logIn(req.body.username, req.body.password, {
    success: function(user){
        if(user.get("tipoUsuario")==1){
            console.log("Usuario Administrador Logeado con Exito  "+user.id)
            req.session.user = user;
            console.log(req.session.user);
            res.redirect("/admin_admin");
        }
        if(user.get("tipoUsuario")==2){
            console.log("Usuario Restaurante Logeado con Exito  "+user.id)
            req.session.user = user;
            console.log(req.session.user);
            res.redirect("/edit_profile");
        }
    },
    error: function(user, error){
        console.log("error name: "+ error.name);
        console.log("error message:  "+ error.message);
        res.redirect("/");
    }   
});
```

};